# Large Size Disparity Between Contract and Its Library Wrapper

Tags: contract-deployment, compilation, library

I have this contract called `Pool.sol`, and an external library for deploying it:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Contracts
import "../Pool.sol";

library DeployerOfPools {
    function deployPool(
        address debtToken,
        address collateralToken,
        int32 leverageTier,
        address oracle
    ) external returns (address) {
        // Create pool
        return address(new Pool{salt: bytes32(0)}(debtToken, collateralToken, leverageTier, oracle));
    }

    function getAddress(
        address factory,
        address debtToken,
        address collateralToken,
        int32 leverageTier,
        address oracle
    ) external pure returns (address) {
        return
            address(
                uint160(
                    uint256(
                        keccak256(
                            abi.encodePacked(
                                hex"ff",
                                factory,
                                bytes32(0), // Salt
                                keccak256(
                                    abi.encodePacked(
                                        type(Pool).creationCode,
                                        abi.encode(debtToken, collateralToken, leverageTier, oracle)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Strangely upon compilation I get the following sizes:

```
 ·····························|··············|·················
 |  Pool                      ·      22.889  ·                │
 ·····························|··············|·················
 |  DeployerOfPools           ·      33.230  ·                │
 ·····························|··············|·················
```

This is the library which is essentially a `Pool.sol` wrapper with a bit of code **is 10 kB or 45% larger**! Why on Earth?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out why. It turns out the sauce is in the constructor. Any imports needed for executing the code in the constructor, will be imported to the wrapping library.

In my specific case, the constructor of `Pool.sol` did some floating point arithmetic, and so it imported the contract `FloatingPoint.sol` making it much larger